# The field was declared with a lazy reference to 'app.model', but app doesn't provide model

Tags: django

Why am I getting errors trying to refer foreign keys?

Four out of Six references are working fine. Why are the other two throwing errors? The models are in the same app and file itself.

I have even listed the app under `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

I have defined all the tables according to my ER diagram. Am I missing something?

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import SET_NULL

# Create your models here.
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
    
class UserTypeDepartment():
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Main Project Contact', 'Main Project Contact'),
        ('Technical Administrator', 'Technical Administrator'),
        ('End-User Requestor', 'End-User Requestor'),
    )    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class UserDepartment(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    department =  models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userType = models.ForeignKey('UserTypeDepartment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)      #THROWS ERROR
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.fname + " " + self.lname
 
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    name = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
    
class UserTypeVendor():
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Vendor Contact', 'Vendor Contact'),
        ('Vendor Technical Contact', 'Vendor Technical Contact'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class UserVendor(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    vendor =  models.ForeignKey('Vendor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userType = models.ForeignKey('UserTypeVendor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)      #THROWS ERROR
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.fname + " " + self.lname

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    purpose = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor =  models.ForeignKey('Vendor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: The field accounts.UserDepartment.userType was declared with a lazy reference to 'accounts.usertypedepartment', but app 'accounts' doesn't provide model 'usertypedepartment'.
The field accounts.UserVendor.userType was declared with a lazy reference to 'accounts.usertypevendor', but app 'accounts' doesn't provide model 'usertypevendor'.
```

**ER Diagram**

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kgY6.jpg)

Comment: `UserTypeDepartment` and `UserTypeVendor` are not models... i.e. they are not inheriting from `models.Model`

Comment: Thank you. That is what I realized after making the post. How silly of me.